# Can I submit a plugin that follows the PSR-2 coding style guide?

Tags: plugin-development

Can I submit a plugin that follows the PSR-2 coding style guide?

**This**

```
if ($a === $b) {

}

$array = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

**instead of**

```
if ( $a === $b ) {

}

$array = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess to the official plugin directory? Yes, the WP's own coding standards are recommended, but not required:

> 4. Keep your code (mostly) human readable.
>
> Intentionally obscuring code by hiding it with techniques or systems [...] Minified code may be used, however the unminified versions should be included whenever possible. We recommend following WordPress Core Coding Standards.
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/

PSR-2 is perfectly readable and there should be no issue with using it.